# dropdown select value resets after onclick after submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<select name="txt" id="txt" style="width:180px;height:27px" data-placeholder="Choose a name ..."  class="chosen-select form-control" >
  <option value="0" selected="selected"> SELECT  </option>
  <option value="1" name="1"> a </option>
  <option value="2" name="2"> b </option>
  <option value="3" name="3"> c</option>
</select>

<br />
<select name="repttype" id="repttype" style="width:180px;height:27px" data-placeholder="Choose a name ..."  class="chosen-select form-control" >
  <option value="0"> SELECT  </option>
  <option value="1" name="check1"> 1 </option>
  <option value="2" name="check2"> 2 </option>
  <option value="3" name="check3"> 3</option>
  <option value="4" name="check4"> 4</option>
</select>

<td  align='center'>
  <input type="button"  name="go" id="go" value="Show" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="issu();"/>
</td>
```

if I select value from 1st dropdown button then click on show I will get the result ao after getting result the same dropdown button should show default value as select

Comment: You should also include the code on `issu()` function.

Comment: Show your `issu()` function code.

Comment: Where are you store the data ? Please mention the other code also.

Comment: Please check again .

Comment: Again you put half inf. Please write what you want and what you tried ?

Comment: What is the use of `onclick="issu();"`?

Comment: that is used for getting ajax call and get data based on the filter..please ignore that

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to your `issue()` function,

```
$('#repttype').val('0');
```

or 
remove `onclick` attribute and add click handler to `#go` like below

```
$('#go').on('click', function(){
    $('#repttype').val('0');
    issue();
});
```

> Note: Don't forgot to Add jQuery, also if you are using these codes in `<form>` than use preventDefault(); to prevent default submit action.

Answer (score 1):

`$(''#txtrcpttype').change(function(){
$('#repttype').prop('selectedIndex' , 0);
});

$(''#repttype').change(function(){
$('#txtrcpttype').prop('selectedIndex' , 0);
});`